# why output of word cloud is different in jupyter notebook and my flask app?

Tags: python, flask

1.Iam trying to genearate  wordcloud images for my project
'''start_time = time.time()
data = pd.read_csv('PRODUCT_Portronics POR-013 Konnect-Trio 3-in-1 Multi-Functional Cable (Grey)_Portronics_10-04-20.csv', delimiter=',')

list_mod=list(map(helperFunctions.remove_punctuation,data['Review_Text']))

## texts = data['Review_Text'].tolist()

tagged_texts = pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, list_mod))
print(tagged_texts)

wordcloud_1, wordcloud_2, wordcloud_3, wordcloud_4,s= helperFunctions.preprocessing(tagged_texts)
print(wordcloud_3)

end=time.time()
list_word1=' '.join(token_data)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, background_color="white").generate(list_word1)
wordcloud.to_file('new.png')
print('@$*****************',end-start_time,'****************')'''

[this is generated in notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJQiA.png)
[this is image in app flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acBFp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of different words taken from the wordlist, by jupyter and by the flask. I have a similar question to flask. Would you answer to my question, it will be great help.